# Digit Sum of three consecutive number is always 6

Tags: number-theory

I'm aware that in the series of 3 consecutive numbers, one of those is a multiple of 2,3 and 4. But I’m wondering how I’ll  explain this observation: 
$$\begin{align}
1+2+3 &= 6\\
4 + 5 + 6 &= 15
\end{align}$$ 
following this pattern continuously I always end up with the digit sum of $6$. I started with $n + (n+1) + (n+2) = 3n + 3$ and the actual number is lets say $10p + q$ hence digit sum is represented by $p + q$... but I cannot connect $3n + 3$ to $p+q$. How sure I am that this will run indefinitely?

Any idea?

Comment: $5+6+7=18$ with digit sum $9$

Answer (score 3):

The “digit sum” is actually the same thing as the remainder when dividing by $9$, except that unless you have the number $0$, the digit sum will be $9$ when it is evenly divisible by $9$ (not too hard exercise).

If the first number you add is a multiple of $3$, then you are adding $3k$, $3k+1$, and $3k+2$. The sum is 
$$3k + (3k+1) + (3k+2) = 9k + 3$$
which will have a “digit sum” of $3$.

If the first number you add is a multiple of $3$ plus $1$, then you are adding $3k+1$, $3k+2$, and $3k+3$; these are the two examples you have. Here you have
$$(3k+1) + (3k+2) + (3k+3) = 9k+ 6$$
giving your observed total of $6$.

Finally, if the first number you add is a multiple of $3$ plus $2$, then you are ading $3k+2$, $3k+3$, and $3k+4$, which gives you
$$(3k+2) + (3k+3) + (3k+4) = 9k + 9$$
Which will give you a “digit sum” of $9$ (or $0$, if you add $-1$, $0$, and $1$).

Comment: My apologies Mr. Arturo, in my haste to see the mathematics, I ignored the first paragraph. I apologise for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexamples:
$2+3+4=9$
$5+6+7=18$ where $1+8=9$
$6+7+8=21$ where $2+1=3$